# Solving numerically a strongly stiff nonlinear ODE system with ill-conditioned Jacobian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system, condition-number

Using Matlab, I am trying to solve numerically the following nonlinear system of ODEs:

$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot B &= -\alpha B -\nu BV   \\ 
  \dot X &= A-\mu_1 X -c E(B)VX \\
  \dot Y &= -\mu_2 Y +c E(B)VX  \\
  \dot V &= kY - (\gamma B + E_0)V - \delta V \\
  \end{aligned}$$

with

$$E(B)=(\gamma B +E_0)e^{-\beta \gamma B}$$

The system tries to capture the dynamics of how the body of an infant reacts to the presence of the dengue virus.

- $V$ is the number of virus.
- $B$ the number of antibody.
- $X$ the number of healthy cells.
- $Y$ the number of infected cells.
- $E$ is a function enhancing the effect of antibodies, depending on the number of antibodies.

Implementing this model and trying different solver, I noticed that solvers `ode15s` and `ode23s` are performing way better than `ode45`. Hence, I deduced that my problem was stiff. But with certain set of parameters I had the following warning from Matlab:

> Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 2.334107e-017.

I worried for a while but I found the malicious ill-conditionned matrix. It's actually that solvers `ode23s` and `ode15s` use the Jacobian of the system. I have then computed myself this Jacobian and found the following:

$$DJ(B,X,Y,V)= \begin{pmatrix}
-\alpha - \nu V & 0 & 0 & - \nu B \\
-c V X E'(B) & -c V E(B)-\mu_1 & 0 & -c X E(B) \\
c V X E'(B) & c V E(B) & -\mu_2 & c E(B) X\\
-\gamma V & 0 & k & -(\gamma B+E_0+\delta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with

$$ E'(B)=e^{-\beta \gamma B}(\gamma-\beta \gamma^2 B-E_0 \beta \gamma)$$

at this point you have to know a bit more about the dynamics of the system. There is two stable points , one where the virus dies , the antibody disappears , the cells stays healthy

$$P_0=(0, \frac{A}{\mu_1},0,0)$$

And another one, depending of the pararameters in a more complex way :

$$ P_1 = \left(0,\mu_2 \frac{E_0+\delta}{k c E_0},\bar{Y}, \frac{k}{E_0+\delta} \bar{Y }\right) \text{  with } \bar{Y}= \frac{A}{\mu_2} - \frac{\mu_1(E_0+\delta)}{k c E_0} $$

which means, basically, that some cells become infected and stay infected, the virus population explodes before stabilising, and the antibodies disappear.

This second point is the problem because lots of initial conditions seems to be attracted by it and it means that $V$ becomes huge (around $10^{12}$) when the total number of cells doesn't exceed $10^{7}$ and the population of antibodies stays below $10^{4}$.

When $V$ becomes huge, I check the Jacobian again, knowing that $\gamma \approx 1$. We have this one value in the left down corner becoming really huge compared to the other values, also the parameter $c$ is around $10^{-10}$, so really it's mostly about this left corner term.

From there I'm not sure what to do. Is there a way to make a time-varying, well-conditioned Jacobian matrix? Or do you know about any other numerical method that could fit my needs?

It doesn't have to be implemented in Matlab. For now, the results I get are mainly garbage.

Comment: Why not compute the Jacobian symbolically? Does the ODE solver allow you to provide the Jacobian?

Comment: hello, yes the solver allows me to do that and that's what I do but I think it replace the symbols with numeric values at computation time before inversion of the Jacobian or whatever it does with the Jacobian.

Comment: Uhmm... are you sure there even is a solution? Nonlinear ODEs can have finite escape time.

Comment: if all initial parameters are above zero , yes it always have a solution . Anyway, I translated my problem in C++ to allow myself to get a better control over the numerical methods used . If I implement myself the implicit method, I should be able to **use substitution to reduce the non linear system to a big non linear equation in dimension 1** and could then use an algorithm not involving a Jacobian (a simple newton method could do the trick)  . Do you think that's a valid strategy ? I can get this 1d equation with the trapezoidal rule already but didn't try to implement it .

Comment: I haven't touched numerical ODEs in over a decade, so I can't offer a lot. However, I am surprised MATLAB does not get the job done. Their solvers should be sophisticated enough to handle stiff problems. Did you check the documentation thoroughly?

Comment: the documentation yes , the numerical method they use no , but I tried every suggestions and every options I could find . They do handle stiff problem but not ill conditionned matrices . when using a implicit method you find yourself with a non linear system to solve and every method I know of use the Jacobian of this system ( like newton's method for a system) . I think that's where the matlab's solver fails . Ideally I should find a way to get rid of the Jacobian .

Comment: I found a solution but it's not optimal . Using the trapezoidal rule , and some substitution , I can reformulate my system as a non linear real valued function , so I can use a newton method without using a jacobian . Problem is it's only order 2 and I don't know any method of order 3 or more that doesn't involve solving a non linear system . I'll try with that for now .

Comment: it is not linear